# Run Apps Script Webapp in the context of a service account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-forms, service-accounts

## Usecase

I am designing a web app that acts as a frontend around a Google Form. I have set up a service account that will perform API calls to collect form responses, and manage form responses. However, [some functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989067/create-google-form-response-through-api) is missing in the Google Forms API, (e.g. managing form responses), so as a workaround, I would like to do it through Apps Script.

## Ideal Authentication Flow

1. I have users share the Google Form to the service account email (`service-account@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com`)
2. I can now access their Google Form with the Google Forms API.
3. I can also access their Google Form through App Script

### Potential Solution #1

In Apps Script, you can share the project with a service account, and even assign it as the owner.
[image]

However, I want to execute the Web App in the context of the service account. I am not sure how to do this.

[image]

Is it possible to deploy an Apps Script under a service account? It is not possible [programmatically](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763096) as far as I can tell. If this is not possible, is it possible to run certain commands in Apps Script as a service account?

Here is a snippet of what I want to run:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  // This line requires access to the Google Form
  const form = FormApp.openById(e.parameter['urlId']);
  // This action is only possible in Apps Script, not through the Google Forms API
  const FormResponse = form.createResponse();
  const res = FormResponse.submit();
  const link = res.getEditResponseUrl();
}
```

The end goal is to be able to perform actions through Apps Script without user interaction. This would look like a `POST` request to the web app, doing the action I need.

### Potential Solution #2

A comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645935/running-google-apps-script-through-https-request-with-service-account-credential?rq=2#comment116070338_65645935) suggests this is possible:

> the access token of the service account can be used for the authorization of Web Apps

So I tried setting the Apps Script to "Execute as User", and passing in the accessToken of my service account in the `Bearer` section. This returned a popup, which I cannot get past.

[image]
[image]

My service account was initialized like this:

```
const authProvider = new auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFilename: filePath,
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    // ...
  ],
});
const authClient = await authProvider.getClient();
  const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec'
  const accessToken = (await authClient.getAccessToken()).token;
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
```

And the Apps Script only requires these two scopes:

```
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ]
```

Is there some way to grant the Apps Script permission to the Service Account?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing everything from the context of a user account, and no longer used the service account. This solution may not work for everyone, as I had to create a special gmail account just for my script.

First, I authenticated my user account using OAUTH and set the type to "offline". I then saved the refresh token I received to a file. Then, I used to refresh token to sign in.

```js
const authClient = new auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
  'http://localhost:8000'
);
authClient.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: process.env.CLIENT_REFRESH_TOKEN,
});
client = forms({
  version: 'v1',
  auth: authClient,
});
  const accessToken = (await authClient.getAccessToken()).token;

const appscriptDeployment =
  'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxe_6S9tzu6bRHE5vYQ4XhyVluotbWmz7mdCd-l8oTM3NfygzksbSziv1hJ8XxgCVr9/exec';

  const url = new URL(appscriptDeployment);
  url.searchParams.append('urlId', formId);

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });
```

Then in AppScript, I set the permissions like:

[image]

```js
/*
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
  When a user visits an app or a program sends the app an HTTP GET request, Apps Script runs the function doGet(e).
*/

function doGet(e) {
  const urlId = e?.parameter['urlId'];
  const form = FormApp.openById(urlId);
  const FormResponse = form.createResponse();
  const res = FormResponse.submit();
  const id = res.getId();
  const timestamp_ms = res.getTimestamp().getTime();
  const link = res.getEditResponseUrl();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    JSON.stringify({ link, id, timestamp_ms })
  );
}
```